# Android Studio 1.5.1 file/Project Structure doesn't open window

Tags: android

When I click on the pulldown menu file/Project Structure nothing happens.  Working fine in my previous version but upgraded today and lost the ability to get the "wizard" style window to set dependencies and such.

Ok, based on suggestion below:  I uninstalled and reinstalled from 1.5.1 to 1.5 still not working. For now I've given up and uninstalled 1.5 and reinstalled 1.3.2 and everything is good. CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S also did not work. I'm thinking there is a problem somewhere as a bug or some other setting I'm missing. I'm sticking with what works until I see someone answer with a fix.

Comment: Try using shortcut CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S. Also try reinstalling it.

Comment: are you able to launch project structure now or not.

Comment: I'm sticking with 1.3.2 for now since I'm running.  I believe it is a bug with 1.5.